# Space between first and second line when styling a text with Drop Cap?

Tags: android

I am trying to style a text with a drop cap but there is a gap between first and second line. Here is my code:

```
    Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(quote);
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(mView.getContext(), R.style.SpecialTextAppearance), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    quoteText.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

This describes the issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191187 and at the end there is a message that said that the bug is fixed. But I still have the problem. [image]

Comment: did you try  like they suggested  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 23) {
        textView.setLineSpacing(textView.getLineHeight(), 0f);
    }

Comment: Yes, I tried but it's the same...

Comment: I tried this and space is reduced .. if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 23) {
            textView.setLineSpacing(textView.getLineHeight(),0.6f);

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:lineSpacingExtra="7sp"/>
```

And If you want to put in your style

```
<style name="YourTextViewStyle" parent="YourTheme">
  <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">7sp</item>
</style>
```